# Upside-down triangle as node shape

Tags: tikz-pgf, shapes

How to give a node the shape of an upside-down triangle (base at top)?

I tried the following:

```
triangle/.style = { regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3, rotate=180}
```

But I don't want the text rotated.

Comment: Try with `shape border rotate` option.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The solution is to use `shape border rotate` instead of `rotate`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} [
    triangle/.style = {fill=blue!20, regular polygon, regular polygon sides=3 },
    node rotated/.style = {rotate=180},
    border rotated/.style = {shape border rotate=180}
  ]
    \node[triangle, node rotated] (a) {Bad triangle};
    \node[triangle, border rotated, right=6cm of a] {Good triangle};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a simpler code for the answer above using `shape border rotate`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[regular polygon,regular polygon sides=3, draw, shape border rotate=180] at (0,0){Non-rotated text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Thanks for your working code.

Comment: Thanks. I am really happy to be able to contribute, even a little. This site has helped me so much.

Comment: Me too. All the best.